# How to get last insert array id from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
comment = await getcomment(resobj);
await comment.post.push(req.body);
await comment.save()
```

How to get last insert array `_id` from mongoose, I can get only comment `_id`, but I need to get the last insert post `_id`

Comment: Post your mongoose schema.

Comment: @Nimesha : Is it working or still having issues ?

Comment: It sorted,  I have added the code below

Comment: @Nimesha : Yes this no much difference between two answers, I would also prefer to send back the `post` as is as response as anyway it will be added as last element to `comment.post` array, but before sending it as response you need to check if `.save()` is successful that's why I've don't it that way, from my answer you no need to do `.pop()` just check `.save()` successful & return `req.body._id`

Answer (score 0):

As your `.save()` function would return the inserted/updated document in response, then you can just do this in code :

```
comment = await getcomment(resobj);
await comment.post.push(req.body);
const resp = await comment.save()

/** If your resp looks like this sample :: 
{_id : 1, post : [{_id : 123, is : true},{_id : 456, is : true},{_id : 789, is : true},{_id : 101112, is : true}]} */

const lastPostId = resp.post.pop()._id; 
/** Above line will get the _id of last element/object of post array, Usually new elements will be added to end of the array, So this should work. Else you might need to do a read */
```

Answer (score 0):

I founded the issue. before going push the data need to create it.

```
  const post = await comment.post.create(req.body);
  await comment.post.push(post);
  await comment.save()
  return post;
```